# URL tracking with Google Analytics and reading from a PHP file

Tags: php, google-analytics

So, basically my team wants to track all subdomains coming from our app (https://blah.net) 
They want to track the following as such

https://product.blah.net 
https://instance.blah.net

And so forth...

I know the way to do this most efficiently is with views and filters, but the problem is they don't want to maintain this in the future as it will get hairy. So, they are using PHP - is there a way to set up URLs in host file to read the traffic and get accurate reporting? I am sorry if this sounds outlandish, I just wanted to give a straight answer if there is one!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this statement: "I know the way to do this most efficiently is with views and filters", but I'm not exactly sure the problem you're trying to solve. Can you elaborate on your end goal?

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by this: "they don't want to maintain this in the future as it will get hairy. So, they are using PHP". Using PHP for what?

Comment: Sure, the goal is to have all of the instances reported for each subdomain, but to not do it the GA way of using views/filters for each. Wasn't sure if it was possible, but they still want to see the actual metrics. Sorry I am confused as well by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two options.

1) If you don't want to do this manually, you can programmatically create views for individual subdomains via the Management API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/

2) If you want to just use a single view for all of your subdomains, you can run reports for data from a particular subdomain via the `filters` param of the Core Reporting API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters